# Python syntax highlighting in VS code is messed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I just noticed that my VSC is kinda messed up with python. Like if I have 4 functions, the middle 2 will not get syntax highlighted and other stuff
Tried till now:

> Reinstalling all python plugins including Magic Python

> Trying Default dark theme

> Reinstalling VSC

[here 2 functions are not properly highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgTYC.png)

[and when I interchanged the position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuiIb.png)

Comment: find out the TextMate scope of the correct and incorrect colored items.

Comment: Agree with @rioV8, and if you don't know how to inspect the Textmate, you can refer to this [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#scope-inspector) for details.

Comment: Okay lemme try and check if it works

Answer (score 0):

You should try to remove settings.json file content.
Control+P and type > settings and open "Open user setting". Than "Open user settings JSON" (on the right top) Than clear file.
Lastly close and reopen VSC.

Comment: yo tried removing settings.json in the .vscode folder (got 2 options, one for default settings in AppData)
should I remove that too? removing one in the workspace didn't do anything

Comment: this is not an answer, more like a comment (try this)